# C++ book, not too long

Tags: c++

I need to learn C++(and C) before summer for a test.
I have the basic concepts of C and Object oriented programming.

Right now I'm looking for a book that's not longer than 400 pages, too learn C++ quickly.

I've seen that a few people suggests "accelerated c++" is that a good book?

I also accept web guides/tutorials/videos if they are good enough.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: The number of pages doesn't really matter. What matters is how the book was written. I doubt you'd be happy reading 400 pages of the standard